# i already input the id_barang, so could you give me an solution?

Tags: php, oracle

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1400 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PABW2"."BASKET"."ID_BARANG") (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:159)

Comment: Error message seems to be telling you the column does not accept null. Expects a value.

Comment: but i already set all of them not null

Comment: If you shared code and say a definition of the table we might be able to help you. As is you provided nothing for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to information you wrote so far, I'd say that you're mistaken.

- error says that you are inserting some values into a table named BASKET, owned by PABW2 user. That table contains column whose name is ID_BARANG
- comment you wrote suggests that ID_BARANG (as well as *all* other columns in that table) are set to be NOT NULL

  - it means that you have to provide values for those columns; they can't be left empty
- however, while performing insert, you didn't provide value for ID_BARANG so Oracle complains
- solution: provide value for ID_BARANG

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table basket
  2    (id_barang   number       NOT NULL,
  3     name        varchar2(20) NOT NULL
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into basket (id_barang, name) values (null, 'Little');
insert into basket (id_barang, name) values (null, 'Little')
                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."BASKET"."ID_BARANG")


SQL> -- OK, let's fix it
SQL> insert into basket (id_barang, name) values (100, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL>
```